# Is there a way to change the permalink structure in Bolt 2?

Tags: bolt-cms

My current blog is on Blogger and my articles have a structure like `/YYYY/MM/slug.html`. Would it be possible to change the permalink structure for specific Contenttypes?

It is also the default for Wordpress.

If not possible, what is the preferred way to deal with those redirections? Something like a route matching `/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<slug>[a-z0-9\-]+)\.html` that would search the database and redirect if found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Generating* URLs like that in bolt would be hard, but *accepting* them is easy. Just set up an  extra route to catch them, coming in.

Create a new binding in `routing.yml`, like this:

```
catcholdentries:
  path:           /{year}/{month}/{slug}
  defaults:       { _controller: 'Bolt\Controllers\Frontend::record', 'contenttypeslug': 'entry' }
  requirements:
    datecreated:    '\d{4}'
    month:          '\d{2}'
```

Combine that with a route to *create* (and catch) URL's like `/2014-12-19/slug-slug`, and you should have something that's close to what you need.

```
entrybinding:
  path:           /{datecreated}/{slug}
  defaults:       { _controller: 'Bolt\Controllers\Frontend::record', 'contenttypeslug': 'entry' }
  contenttype:    entries
  requirements:
    datecreated:    '\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}'
```

Comment: Would it not be possible to create a binding like `/{year}/{month}/{slug}`? What is preventing it? Perhaps some kind of virtual property could be added?

Comment: Yes, it could be made. It just never came up. The link is built in `src/Content.php`, around line 776. Add 'month', 'year', 'day' keys to the passed array, and you should be halfway there.